# How to repair Creative Inspire Speakers 2.1 Volume Control Wheel?

Tags: desktop-computer, speakers

Due to dust or something, the Volume Control Wheel does not work properly. Volume goes to one speaker, and other gets muted. Vice versa. When I carefully turn the wheel sometimes the Volume works properly or sometimes with noise or muted one side.

As I write this, I've cleaned it up with Petrol drops. PCB is drying. I chose Petrol because Contact Cleaner is expensive solution. Am I correct or any other method could be used?

Comment: the little wheel in a rougly Y shaped base? Mine's mucking up, pondering just chopping and replacing the unit tho.

Comment: I googled for the image, here we go: http://sys.cs.rice.edu/~twngan/sale/c15-3.jpg I don't know if this spare is available or not in my country. Search results point out that Creative doesn't make spares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contacts within the volume control are apparently slightly oxidized, causing the intermittent behavior you are reporting. A one time purchase of contact cleaner will last a lifetime (or until you lend it to someone) and is the best way to fix these common problems. Since oil is a non-conductive substance, using petrol drops may make the problem worse.

Comment: I tried with Petrol but it doesn't work. Some search results said it worked for some but not in my case. Volume comes in the right speaker and Sub-woofer now. When I turn the wheel cracking sound still coming. I shall try for the Contact Cleaner else I'll buy one. but it's expensive in my country (a good one for $30+). Do you have any idea whether I could get this spare in the market? Search results say Creative doesn't make them? Very strange

Answer (score 3):

A little counter intuitive but loosening the screws at the base of the unit should temporarily fix the problem on many units - loosen it slightly, get it to a level that works and use the computer's volume control for the rest. Its cheaply made junk, so considering that a headphone volume control unit is about 3 dollars on Amazon, I wouldn't bother with the contact cleaner, personally.

I'd probably swap it for a cable with no inline volume control (I used a 3.5mm male to male cable) , or replace it with something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004GIFBM4) thing with an appropriate gender changer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did unscrew and removed the tiny PCB to clean it with a few drops of Petrol. This helped to some but not in my case. Stereo Extension Cord w/ Volume Control product looks promising. I shall try to search in my location. We have no Amazon. Swap it for a cable with no inline volume control? Does dumping Volume control diminishes any Sound Output or Quality? Thanks

Comment: Quality should be same or better. It will be stuck at full volume, so you will need to control it with the controls on the PC. The amazon link is an example rather than a product recommendation - just to point out such things exist

Comment: Thank you again for the response. I would keep 'bypass' as last resort.

Comment: I can't vote until I get 15 reputation points! :( Can't I *accept* more than one answer as solution or more likely to be correct/true?

Comment: You can only accept one answer. I personally wouldn't worry about the upvote, my interest in this question is *entirely* since I have the same volume control unit and the same problem.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the alcohol cleaning tip. I opened the volume control housing and then used an alcohol pad I got from the pharmacy (very cheap); stuck it in under the volume control from different sides and turned the knob back and forth. Tried to wipe everything clean. Even without being able to properly get the pad into the insides of the volume control, it made a significant improvement.

Comment: Diluted alcohol in water, pushing dental floss with an exacto knife into the knob, and flossing and turning it around did it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The circuit board is oxidized. Clean with vinegar and alcohol based solution. Works like wonder.

Answer (score 0):

I flooded a few drops of 99% isopropyl alcohol on the center of the control knob. I then used a Giotto air rocket to blow dry the alcohol away. The control knob was for a cheap $30 pair of 2.1 speakers, Logitech 2.1 Z313. There is no screw to even tighten or loosen. The dust in the potentiometer was cleared and now works like a charm.

The expensive $200+ Creative Labs Inspire P7800 control wheel is fixed by simply tightening the center screw.